# Magento - Run Sql Query after save

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a custom module for magento which is working fine. What I want is that I have a sql update query which is run on form load, whereas I want it to run after save/submit.

The first of the form.php file is like this:

```
<?php
class Mywebsolutions_Autopriceupdate_Block_Adminhtml_Autopriceupdate_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
        protected function _prepareForm()
        {
                $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
                $this->setForm($form);
                $fieldset = $form->addFieldset("autopriceupdate_form", array("legend"=>Mage::helper("autopriceupdate")->__("Item information")));

                        $fieldset->addField("date", "date", array(
                        "label"     =>Mage::helper ("autopriceupdate")->__("Date"),
                        "name" => "date",

                        'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
                        'format' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM)
        ));

                        $fieldset->addField("goldrate", "text", array(
                        "label" => Mage::helper("autopriceupdate")->__("GoldRate"),
                        "name" => "goldrate",
                        ));
                        /*          
                         $fieldset->addField('status', 'select', array(
                        'label'     => Mage::helper('autopriceupdate')->__('Status'),
                        'values'   => Mywebsolutions_Autopriceupdate_Block_Adminhtml_Autopriceupdate_Grid::getValueArray2(),
                        'name' => 'status',
                        ));*/

                if (Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->getAutopriceupdateData())
                {
                    $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->getAutopriceupdateData());
                    Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setAutopriceupdateData(null);
                } 
                elseif(Mage::registry("autopriceupdate_data")) {
                    $form->setValues(Mage::registry("autopriceupdate_data")->getData());
                }

                return parent::_prepareForm();
        }
}
```

The second part of from.php which I want to run after submit/save

```
//database write adapter custom query by myweb solutions
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

//update query for 22 carat making charges

$write->query("update catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev, (select value,entity_id from catalog_product_entity_varchar
where attribute_id=139) cpev1, eav_attribute eav, catalog_product_entity p, autopriceupdate a, catalog_product_flat_1 cpf
SET  cpev.value =round((((a.goldrate)/24)*22*cpf.weight)*cpev1.value/100,-1)
where

a.autopriceupdate_id=(
    SELECT max(autopriceupdate_id) FROM autopriceupdate
    )
and
eav.entity_type_id =4
AND eav.attribute_code = 'price'
AND p.entity_id = cpev.entity_id
AND p.attribute_set_id =10
AND cpev.attribute_id=140
and cpev1.entity_id = cpev.entity_id
AND cpf.entity_id =cpev.entity_id
AND cpf.metal_purity=4");

//myweb solutions using a time gap before execution of next query;
sleep(5);

//update query for 18 carat making charges

$write->query("update catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev, (select value,entity_id from catalog_product_entity_varchar
where attribute_id=139) cpev1, eav_attribute eav, catalog_product_entity p, autopriceupdate a, catalog_product_flat_1 cpf
SET  cpev.value =round((((a.goldrate)/24)*18*cpf.weight)*cpev1.value/100,-1)
where

a.autopriceupdate_id=(
    SELECT max(autopriceupdate_id) FROM autopriceupdate
    )
and
eav.entity_type_id =4
AND eav.attribute_code = 'price'
AND p.entity_id = cpev.entity_id
AND p.attribute_set_id =10
AND cpev.attribute_id=140
and cpev1.entity_id = cpev.entity_id
AND cpf.entity_id =cpev.entity_id
AND cpf.metal_purity=3");


//myweb solutions using a time gap before execution of next query;
sleep(5);

//update query for 22 carat price
$write->query("update catalog_product_entity_decimal val, eav_attribute eav, catalog_product_entity p, autopriceupdate a, 
catalog_product_flat_1 cpf, 
catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev
SET  val.value =round(((((a.goldrate)/24)*22*cpf.weight)+cpev.value),-1)
WHERE 
a.autopriceupdate_id=(
    SELECT max(autopriceupdate_id) FROM autopriceupdate
    )
and
eav.entity_type_id =4
AND eav.attribute_code = 'price'
AND p.entity_id = val.entity_id
AND p.entity_id = cpev.entity_id
AND cpev.attribute_id=140
AND p.attribute_set_id =10
AND val.attribute_id = eav.attribute_id
AND cpf.entity_id =val.entity_id
AND cpf.metal_purity=4"); 


//myweb solutions using a time gap before execution of next query;
sleep(5);

$write->query("update catalog_product_entity_decimal val, eav_attribute eav, catalog_product_entity p, autopriceupdate a, 
catalog_product_flat_1 cpf,
catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev
SET  val.value =round(((((a.goldrate)/24)*18*cpf.weight)+cpev.value),-1)
WHERE 
a.autopriceupdate_id=(
    SELECT max(autopriceupdate_id) FROM autopriceupdate
    )
and
eav.entity_type_id =4
AND eav.attribute_code = 'price'
AND p.entity_id = val.entity_id
AND p.entity_id = cpev.entity_id
AND cpev.attribute_id=140
AND p.attribute_set_id =10
AND val.attribute_id = eav.attribute_id
AND cpf.entity_id =val.entity_id
AND cpf.metal_purity=3");
```

How this can done in magento.